# How do i make last click on Nested AlertDialog as a primary button.setOnClickListener

Tags: android, nested, android-alertdialog

**EDIT**: I have a situation Nested AlertDialog like this :

```
public void showMsgDialog(){
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MapsActivity.this);
        builder.setMessage(MapsActivity.this.getString(R.string.petunjuk_1))
        .setPositiveButton("Lanjut1", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                showMsgDialog1();
                SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("MYPREFS", MODE_PRIVATE);
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
                editor.putString("key1", key1);
                editor.apply();
            }
        })
        .setNegativeButton("Tutup", null)
        .create()
        .show();
    }

    public void showMsgDialog1(){
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MapsActivity.this);
        builder.setMessage(MapsActivity.this.getString(R.string.petunjuk_2))
        .setPositiveButton("Lanjut2", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                showMsgDialog2();
            }
        })
        .setNegativeButton("Tutup", null)
        .create()
        .show();
    }
    public void showMsgDialog2(){
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MapsActivity.this);
        builder.setMessage(MapsActivity.this.getString(R.string.petunjuk_3))
                .setPositiveButton("Lanjut3", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        showMsgDialog3();
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton("Tutup", null)
                .create()
                .show();
    }
    public void showMsgDialog3(){
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MapsActivity.this);
        builder.setMessage(MapsActivity.this.getString(R.string.petunjuk_4))
                .setPositiveButton("Lanjut4", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        showMsgDialog4();
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton("Tutup", null)
                .create()
                .show();
    }
    public void showMsgDialog4(){
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MapsActivity.this);
        builder.setMessage(MapsActivity.this.getString(R.string.petunjuk_5))
                .setPositiveButton("Lanjut5", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        showMsgDialog5();
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton("Tutup", null)
                .create()
                .show();
    }
    public void showMsgDialog5(){
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MapsActivity.this);
        builder.setMessage(MapsActivity.this.getString(R.string.petunjuk_5))
                .setPositiveButton("Selesai",null)
                .create()
                .show();
    }
```

**EDIT**, and then i create method:

```
public void choose(){
        if(key1 == true){
         // go to ShowMsgDialog number you want
        }elseif(key2 == true){
        // go to ShowMsgDialog number you want
        }
    } and so on..
```

which is fine, now the situation is, if user goes to another activity, and comeback to Dialog Activity, it will go to the first AlertDialog again. 
How do i set the last AlertDialog `setPositiveButton` onClick as it Last click on every nested AlertDialog, and make a logic if `petunjuk` button is click, it will go to the last click of the Nested AlertDialog, otherwise it will go the first AlertDialog again. until the last button `Selesai` button is clicked. it will stay forever on the last click. any help appreciate it. thanks

Comment: Please create separate method to show separate dialog. If you do it you can show any dialog based on any condition. And it should make it human readable format as well. Thanks.

Comment: ok, hold on, i'll try it.

Comment: Save different tag in a variable or in `SharedPreference`. Next time show your required dialog based on saved value.

Comment: could you give one example is for saving different tag in SharedPreference please in this case, and an example to show required dialog based on saved value. please...in this case

Comment: Please find how to save and read data from `SharedPreference`. It will help you. https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared-preferences#java

Comment: i already know using SharedPreference on EditText and TextView, but can i use it based onClick, i never try that, and i don't know how

Comment: Why not. On each click update your previous value. So that you know which dialog's button was click and now which dialog you have to show.

Comment: ahhh, i seee, ok,ok appreciate it your help man.i'll give it a try

Comment: I have manage to create separate method dialog, but i dont know how to set, setPositiveButton "lanjut1" as value, i need an example :(

Comment: Can you share what have you did so far?

Comment: I already EDIT my question, in there. now, i don't know how to set .setPositiveButton in each every showMsgDialog as value to i'm using in choose method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can we make show dialog in this format?

```
int messageIds[] = {R.string.petunjuk_1, R.string.petunjuk_2, ....};
String buttonTexts[] = {"Lanjut1", "Lanjut2", .....};

public void showMsgDialog(final int id){
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MapsActivity.this);
    builder.setMessage(MapsActivity.this.getString(messageIds[id]))
    .setPositiveButton(buttonTexts[id], new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

            SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("MYPREFS", MODE_PRIVATE);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
            editor.putString("key", buttonTexts[id]);
            editor.apply();
            if(id < buttonTexts.length() - 1) {
                showMsgDialog(id+1);
            }
        }
    })
    .setNegativeButton("Tutup", null)
    .create()
    .show();
}
```

Call show dialog by

```
showMsgDialog(0);
```

** Edited **

```
private void onPetunjukButtonClick () {
    SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("MYPREFS", MODE_PRIVATE);
    String data = preferences.getString("key", ""); 
    int index = 0;
    if (!data.equals ("")) {
        int i = 0;
        for (String text : dataTexts) {
            if (data.equals (text) {
                index = i;
                break;
            }
            i++;
        }
    }
    showMsgDialog (index);
}
```

Comment: Jesus.. mother of christ.. Budha's god...
i''m so.. it's more Elegant...
omg... Efficient, Elegant, i'm gonna learn this.. 
so it's increase by 0,1,2,3,4.. if id < buttonTexts[].length -1

Comment: wait, i'm still learning the math. Mr Md Sufi Khan thank you for your kind. i will learn this lesson.

Comment: Yes. And we put `id < length() -1` to avoid `IndexOutOfBoundException` and also we don't want to handle that part which is greater than our array size, don't we? :)

Comment: Isn't it more readable, flexible and handy than your first code? :)

Thank you for accept it :)

Comment: Yes, sir ! :). true of indeed. :-)

Comment: Sir, it does correct but how do i set the primary button it will go to the LAST click of the String buttonTexts[] series {Lanjut1, Lanjut2...}, otherwise it will go the first AlertDialog again. until the last button finish is clicked.

Comment: if we press Lanjut1, it goes to the next dialog, and so on, Lets say a user on Lanjut2 dialog, they shut the dialog and move to another activity, when they go to dialog activity again, when they press Petunjuk button it should go to Lanjut2 dialog again, not to the first one, and same to the dialog 3, 4 and 5. when a user at that specific dialog, and shut the dialog, when they press again, it should to the last dialog they went.

Comment: That's simple. When user pressed `Petunjuk` button, read stored data. Then find the data index from `buttonTexts` array. As we stored button text as value. Then call `showMsgDialog` with that index number.

Comment: i'm making new method like this, but doesn't work. 
public void choose(final int id){
        SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("MYPREFS", MODE_PRIVATE);
        String key = preferences.getString("key", buttonTexts[id]);
        showMsgDialog(0);
    }
then i called by choose(0);

Comment: Share your `Petunjuk` button event.

Comment: i quit sir, i change my method button, it's really hard for me to realize that algorithm, basically i do it as you say, read stored data, find the data index, then call showMsgDialog , it didn't happen. 
SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("MYPREFS", MODE_PRIVATE);
String data =  preferences.getString("key", buttonTexts[id]);
showMsgDialog(data);
but of course it will not work, because dialog asked for int, and the data is String, i try to convert to integer.ParseInt(data)  but cause error again. i create int id as variable to pass to buttonTexts[id]

Comment: You made a mistake. Read data returns you a string (name of your dialog's positive button text which was stored in `dataTexts` array). Now you have to find the index of read `data` value from `dataTexts`array. Then you have to call `showMsgDialog` method by that index. It must work.

Comment: I edited the answer. Can you please try that? Hope it may help you to understand the logic. :)  * I edited the answer from my mobile. So it may have some syntax error. As I don't have pc right now to check the code. So please fix those error. *